# Number of terms in this code series?

Tags: c

Given a C code

```
for(i=n,j=0 , i>0,i/=2 ,  j+=i)
```

What is the value of j after termination of for loop?

In the solution in my book, it starts with:

```
j=n+n/2 +n/4+....+log n terms.
```

Now I can understand how there are log n terms in the above series.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That's not valid C code.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to end it with a semicolon. Now let me know the solution.

Comment: You need to add more than one semi-colon; so please correct your question till the C code is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is *log<sub>2</sub> n*, that is the number of binary bits (or the rank of the highest 1 bit) in the binary representation of n

And you made a typo, you probably mean

```
 for(i=n,j=0 ; i>0 ;  (i/=2), (j+=i));
```

So you start with `i==n` then you halve it till 0 is reached (hence the *log<sub>2</sub> n* number of loops).

Comment: By "binary bits" do you actually mean "binary bit digits"?

Comment: Yes, bit is a binary digit, i.e. a digit in base 2

Comment: Basile , please explain me how can we reach to log n base 2. I still cant get. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

This is a sum of geometric series with *log<sub>2</sub>n* elements. The sum depends on your `n`, but in any case it's bounded by`2n`. Theory is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression

Comment: Thanks everyone for your answers.